# Can I place \includegraphics command before \begin{document}?

Tags: graphics

Can I place `\includegraphics` command before `\begin{document}`? I see in sharelatex they are doing like that but in texstudio I am writing the same code but I get the error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! No, it's not possible. No typesetting can take place before `\begin{document}` (unless it's hidden in some `\sbox`).

Comment: *I see in sharelatex they are doing like that [...]* Who? Where? Add a link. Anyway, as egreg wrote, a "naked" `\includegraphics` is not legal before the beginning of the document.

Comment: Either it's in a box or wrapped in a `\newcommand{...}` definition or another macro that stores the values only, then it's possible of course, but this is not typesetting then

Comment: Here is the link to that video. Minutes 2:0 you can see that code.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFAQd0ueIMc

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFAQd0ueIMc

Comment: @Michael: That's what I meant: `\includegraphics{...}` is stored in another macro again (by `\title`), but it isn't displayed there! `\title` uses `\gdef\@title` for storing content, i.e. using another macro (register) to store the title stuff

Comment: Note that the `\includegraphics` command is in the argument to `\title`. In my opinion, `\title` and `\author` should go *after* `\begin{document}`, others differ. In any case, the argument to `\title` is stored away for usage at `\maketitle`. It's something like a `\newcommand`.

Comment: So my final goal is to put a logo after Institution name in following code. But I can not place the logo in the right position.\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \title{{Thesis title}\\
   {\Large Institution name}}
 {\begin{figure}[h]
   \includegraphics[width=2.3 in]{C:/logo.jpg}
  \end{figure}}
 \author{Author }
 \date{December 2015}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}

Comment: @Michael: Don't use `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` then since you want the image on the titlepage, not let floating it away to some other place.

Answer (score 4):

Display of graphics or Text/tables, showing page numbers/headers etc. i.e. anything which is really connected with text etc. is typesetting.

Typesetting is not possible with LaTeX before `\begin{document}`.

If text/content is to be stored, either in boxes or a wrapper macro, this can be done of course, see the `\blindtext` command from `blindtext` package, which is definitely stored before `\begin{document}` (since it's in a package), but you can't use `\blindtext` before `\begin{document}` directly.

The example videos provided in the link show basically

```
\title{%
   \includegraphics{foo}
}
```

The `\title{#1}` macro is effectively doing this`\gdef\@title{#1}`, i.e. using another macro to store the content, designed to be used by `\maketitle` later on.